# How to use socat to implement a base64 decoding proxy?

Tags: networking, socket, socat

The goal: bidirectional communication while decode in a unidirectional way the incoming data

Theory: suppose to have a proxy/ server that listens on port 8080 which needs to handle multiple clients at once. The data coming in is base64 encoded, it should be decoded and forwarded to another port ( 80 ).

Practice: I would like to use socat because of all its features ( and also because it is the only one I know that can do all these things, if you know something else could be fine too ):

- tcp to tcp
- ***udp to tcp***
- ***fork and reuseaddr***
- exec commands

I'm looking for something like that:

```
socat tcp-listen:8080,reuseaddr,fork exec:/path/to/myscript.sh
```

with /path/to/myscript.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec base64 -d | socat - tcp:localhost:80
```

But this sadly does not fit my case because is not completely bidirectional

Comment: Does it work better if you replace `exec base64 -d` with `stdbuf -o0 recode /b64`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is probably that `base64 -d` (GNU `base64` for me) buffers its output, and by the look of it, can't be told not to. Same goes for `openssl base64 -d` from my tests. GNU `recode` can be told not to buffer with GNU `stdbuf` though.

So with `socat` 2, you should be able to do something like:

```
socat tcp-listen:8080,fork,reuseaddr \
      'exec1:stdbuf -o0 recode /b64 % nop | tcp:localhost:80'
```

With `socat` 1, you could do:

```
socat tcp-listen:8080,fork,reuseaddr \
      'system:"stdbuf -o0 recode /b64 | socat - tcp:localhost:80"'
```

Which is essentially the same as yours but with the intermediate script inlined (and the non-buffering base64 decoding).

Comment: I installed recode and I tried what you suggest, but it gives me an error sadly. The command I used: socat tcp-listen:8080,fork,reuseaddr 'exec:stdbuf -o0 recode /b64 % nop | tcp\:localhost\:80'. The error: recode: fopen (%): No such file or directory. By the way, thanks for your help! (:

Comment: You'd need `socat` 2 for that address chaining capability.

Comment: @hyogy, see edit for socat 1.

Comment: AAH the second version of socat! I thought you mistyped the 2! ahah sorry! I tried your edit, it works!!! Thanks!!!

Comment: One more tip please: what about rot13 rather than base64 ?

Comment: @hyogy, socat 2 does come with a host of new features but still is beta (though the one included in the socat package of a few Linux distributions) and has not seen much update in the last 5 years unfortunately. socat 1 seems to be actively maintained.

Comment: @hyogy, you can use `stdbuf -o0 tr` with the right translation map for rot13. Something like `tr a-zA-Z n-za-mN-ZA-M` (untested).

Comment: It works!!! Thanks for your kind help!!

Comment: Hello!(: I have another hard question! ahah if you want to take a look at: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/665339/how-to-use-socat-to-implement-a-proxy

Comment: @hyogy, I suspect it's just `'system:"stdbuf -o0 tr... | socat - tcp:localhost:80 | stdbuf -oO tr..."'`. But I don't have time to look into it atm. Feel free to answer your own question if that works.

Comment: Thanks for your help!(: Sadly it does not work! It gives multiple errors! The errors: "stdbuf: invalid mode ‘O’
2021/08/19 08:57:33 socat[8404] E write(1, 0x5612d366f000, 2): Broken pipe
tr: write error: Broken pipe
tr: write error
2021/08/19 08:57:38 socat[8399] E waitpid(): child 8401 exited with status 125
stdbuf: invalid mode ‘O’
2021/08/19 08:58:26 socat[8411] E write(1, 0x560de4853000, 2): Broken pipe". Don' t worry by the way if you don't have time!

Comment: OK nevermind, found the problem. Everything works fine. Please when you have time post the answer, I will mark it as solution, you deserve all these points(: